# Render Blazor child component with parameters

Tags: c#, components, blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I'm new to Blazor and I'm currently working on a Blazor Webassembly .net 5.0 application.

I try to figure out the correct way to

- render a child component
- from a parent component
- on button click (form submit)
- pass parameters from the parent component to => the child component

My current solution seems to work, but unfortunately  **it ends in an infinite rendering loop**: I use the `OnParametersSetAsync` method in the child component to handle the data loading.

Side note: I use Telerik Blazor components, but it should have no impact.

1. My **parent component** looks like this:

- **View** (parent)

```
// I want to submit a form to set a bool = true, and then to rend the child component - is that ok?
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@(async () => await StartEverything())">
            <label for="OrderNumber">OrderNumber: </label>
            <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="OrderNumber" Id="OrderNumber" />
            <TelerikButton ButtonType="@ButtonType.Submit">Start Everything</TelerikButton>
</EditForm>


@if (ShowChild)
{
    <MyChildComponent OrderNumber="OrderNumber"/>
}
else
{
    <div>Please enter an order number.</div>
}
```

- **Code Behind** (parent)

```
public class MyParentComponent : ComponentBase {

 protected int OrderNumber { get; set; }

 protected bool ShowChild { get; set; }

 protected async Task StartEverything()
 {
     if (OrderNumber > 0)
     {
         await Task.FromResult(ShowChild = true);
     }
 }
}
```

2. My **child component** looks like this:

- **View** (child)

```
@if (Customer != null)
{
      <p>@Customer.CustomerName</p>
      <p>@Customer.AgencyName</p>
}
```

- **Code Behind** (child)

```
public class MyChildComponent : ComponentBase {

 // I need this Parameter sent from my parent component
 [Parameter]
 public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

 protected CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }

 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
     var parameterForQuery = OrderNumber; // this should hold the value sent from the parent component

     // Load Customer ViewModel Data here - is this the correct event? What is the best approach?
 }
}
```

- **Item ViewModel**

```
public class CustomerViewModel 
{
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }

   public string AgencyName { get; set; }  
}
```

Do you know how to correctly render a Child Component within a Parent Component and pass parameters from the Parent Component to the child component - then render the child component ONLY ON BUTTON CLICK (form submit, no infinite render loop)?

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend going through https://blazor-university.com.  It's the site that kind of got me kick-started when I first started with Blazor.

In regard to your question, I recommend the following:

https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/

In particular, the following statement should prove useful in your case (from that link):

> **OnInitialized / OnInitializedAsync**
>
> This method is only executed once when the component is first created.
> If the parent changes the component’s parameters at a later time, this
> method is skipped.

It seems likely that simply changing which method you override will solve your problem, since `OnParametersSetAsync` behaves as you've described, and 'OnInitializedAsync' behaves as you want. :D